# What is this error in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

If I use this code the page displays:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("m_welcome", "mod");
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view("test.php", array());
    //exit;
}
}
```

if I comment the `//exit;` it shows all the page. If I don't comment it, the page doesn't display anything. It's very weird.

Comment: try load the view without the empty array "$this->load->view("test.php");". Have your view test.php some php code?

Answer (score 2):

You are cancelling execution early - it's not an error, but the expected behaviour in CI.

If you exit at that point, you are stopping the execution from sending output to the browser. The response from what ever is in the route method will not be sent to the parent method handling the request & response.

Comment: which function help put it out directly?

Comment: @jewelnguyen8 You can that using: `$this->output->set_output("any data you want to output");` from inside the controller methods.